# Updating the parent table considering the values of the child table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window, oracle12c

I have table Parent_tbl which consists of 3 columns H_N, Col58 and Type this both the first two columns will be having the same values, only the column type differs.

I have a child table where col58 defines the relationship with the parent but rest of the columns in child_tbl is specific to that table only H_N is the unique column in both of the tables.

I need to update TYPE as EXCHANGE in PARENT_TBL when ever i find the the CHILD_TBL I_STATUS having all the values like S,R and V else the parent_tbl type remains untouched, how can we do this ?

The Parent_tbl.col58 = 1140 that type should be 'EXCHANGE' because child_tbl.col58 = 1140 is having every letter i.e S,R,V.

Here is the DDL for the samples.

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT_TBL (
    H_N number, 
    col58 number,
    TYPE varchar(100)
);
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (2,2,'SALE');
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (16,16,'SALE');
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (20,20,'SALE');
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (34,34,'VOID');
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (38,38,'SALE');
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (102,102,'SALE');
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (111,111,'SALE');
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (117,117,'SALE');
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (1140,1140,'RETURN');
Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (131,131,'SALE');

commit;

CREATE TABLE CHILD_TBL
(
    I_STATUS varchar(100),
    H_n number,
    col58 number
);


Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('S',3,2);
Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('S',5,2);
Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('S',7,2);
Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('S',8,2);
Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('S',10,2);
Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('S',1141,1140);
Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('V',1142,1140);
Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('R',1143,1140);
Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('R',1144,1140);
Insert into CHILD_TBL (I_STATUS,H_N,COL58) values ('S',1145,1140);

commit;
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
  truncate table PARENT_TBL ;
     Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (2,2,'SALE');
        Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (16,16,'SALE');
        Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (20,20,'SALE');
        Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (34,34,'VOID');
        Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (38,38,'SALE');
        Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (102,102,'SALE');
        Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (111,111,'SALE');
        Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (117,117,'SALE');
        Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (1140,1140,**'EXCHANGE'**);
        Insert into PARENT_TBL (H_N,COL58,TYPE) values (131,131,'SALE');
```

Comment: Give the expected output as well for the data given for 2 tables.

Comment: Utsav, I have added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
update PARENT_TBL p
set TYPE='EXCHANGE'
where exists 
( select 1
    from child_tbl c
    where
    i_status in ('S','R','V')
    and c.col58=p.col58
     group by col58
     having count(distinct(i_status))=3
)
```

Explanation:

```
select col58 
from child_tbl c
where
  i_status in ('S','R','V')
  group by col58
  having count(distinct(i_status))=3
```

This will give you the `col58` where `count(distinct(i_status))=3` after the filter  `i_status in ('S','R','V')`. So it will be `3` only if there are at least 1 each status of `'S','R','V'`. Now use this in `exists` clause and add 
a where condition in the above query `and c.col58=p.col58` to join it with the `parent` table while updating.

Please try this first of your test data and try this without committing the original data. Commit only when you are sure that you got expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Find rows in child table (CHILD_TBL) with proper grouping and use `merge`:

```
merge into parent_tbl p
using (select col58 
         from child_tbl
         group by col58
         having count(decode(i_status, 'S', 1)) > 0 
            and count(decode(i_status, 'R', 1)) > 0
            and count(decode(i_status, 'V', 1)) > 0) c
on (p.col58 = c.col58)
when matched then update set type = 'EXCHANGE'
```